# Вернуть 2 return в Django

Tags: django, return

Проект такой: пользователь заполняет поля, а сайт выдает заполненное заявление. После заполнения хочу, чтобы его перенаправило на страницу "Успешной отправки формы" и само заявление начало скачиваться. Но в функциях можно сделать только один return. Как сделать, чтобы они выполнялись обе?

```
return FileResponse(open(name_file, 'rb')) # Это выдает файл, который автоматически начинает скачиваться
return render(request, "succes.html") # Это перенаправляет на страницу успешной отправки формы
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это будет работать, но попробуйте:

```
return FileResponse(open(name_file, 'rb')), render(request, "succes.html")
```

Comment: Так не работает